# Create a high-resolution device-context

Tags: delphi, winapi, rtf, gdi

In order to solve problems with rendering of RichText, for which there is no other elegant alternative, I require providing a high-resolution device-context (e.g. 600 dpi) to the text-service interface.

Is there a way to create such a device-context? I do not want to rely on an installed printer driver or something similar.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=device+context+dpi) found [this discussion](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/200607/0607062675.html).

Comment: I stumbled about that during my research, too... unfortunately there's no solution to my problem... working with metafiles btw involves the same problems which require me to have a high-resolution dc